# advantage of db session?

Tags: session, database

while I was installing Magento, I saw db storage option. There were 'file system' and 'db'.

What is advantage of saving sessions in DB? I can't think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if your application uses multiple servers, but only a single database there's no need to synchronize your sessions between the servers if they are stored in the database. If the sessions are stored on the server (file system), your load balancer will have to guarantee that users are always directed to the same server during a session, or the sessions need to be replicated on all servers.

I'm not sure if it serves a different purpose in Magento.